# choose the correct statement in given Norms?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

[image]

choose the correct statement :

1) $U_\infty$ is a subset of $U_1$

2) $U_1$ is a subset of $U_\infty$

3) $U_\infty$ is equal $U_1$

My attempt : I know that  for option (1)  and (2)  $X_1 \leq X_\infty$, so
$U_1 \leq U_\infty \dots$ so $U_1$ is a subset of $U_\infty$. Therefore option (1) is not true.

For option 3) it may be true or may not be true... so it is not correct.

Is my answer correct? 
Please, tell me the solutions... I would be thankful

Answer (score 1):

What you probably meant by $X_1 \le X_\infty$ (as this is not true) is $\|\cdot\|_1 \le \|\cdot\|_\infty$.

Truly, for all $f \in C[0,1]$ we have:

$$\|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx \le \int_0^1 \|f\|_\infty\,dx = \|f\|_\infty$$

Also, you have to be careful, as this implies $U_\infty \subseteq U_1$, not the other way around as you said: take $f \in U_\infty$. This means $\|f\|_\infty < 1$. But then also we have $\|f\|_1 \le \|f\|_\infty < 1$. So $f \in U_1$.

The other inclusion is not true:

Define $f \in C[0,1]$ as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
2-4x,  & \text{if $x \in \left[0, \frac12\right]$} \\
0, & \text{if $x \in \left\langle\frac12, 1\right]$}
\end{cases}, \quad x \in [0,1]$$

We have $\|f\|_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, but $\|f\|_\infty = 2$, so $f \in U_1 \setminus U_\infty$. So $U_1 \not\subseteq U_\infty$.

Thus, the correct answer is $(1)$, as $U_\infty \subsetneq U_1$.

Comment: thanks a lots @ mechanodroid...im getting option option 2  but   not option 1 that  u said  that  f ∈ U∞ and f ∈ U1 and | f |1   ≤  | f |∞ <1,,my doubt is that ,,,how can u claim that U1 is not a subset  of U∞ ?

Comment: @kalomlego I showed that $U_\infty \subseteq U_1$ and I found an element $f \in U_1 \setminus U_\infty$. As I pointed out, $\|\cdot\|_1 \le \|\cdot\|_\infty$ does not imply $U_1 \subseteq U_\infty$, it rather implies $U_\infty \subseteq U_1$. Also, about your deduction, having $A \subseteq B$ is not enough to conclude $B \not\subseteq A$.

Comment: ok,,,@mechanodroid,,thanks once again for clearing my doubts ,,,im voting up ur answer now..